# Origin of the phrase 'redress the balance'

Tags: phrase-origin

It seems to me that the word 'redress' is seldom used without the word 'balance', so I was thinking that the phrase "redress the balance" might have origins in some trade or other, but I can't find out much about it after much (well, a bit of) googling.  Can anybody shed any light on it at all, or does it not really count as a phrase on its own – is that just what we have all decided to say when we want to convey something like 'make things fair again'?

Comment: I’ve actually never seen ‘redress’ used with ’balance’.

Comment: ***Redress the balance*** definitely is  a set phrase:   Restore equality in a situation.
‘an opportunity to redress the balance in their fortunes’ (ODO)

Comment: The usage of redress, though less common than in the past, is not  limited to the expression "redress the balance". https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=redress+the+balance%2C+redress+&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Credress%20the%20balance%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Credress%3B%2Cc0

Comment: Agreeing with @Jim, I am more familiar with the redressing of grievances. "The right to petition government for redress of grievances is the right to make a complaint to, or seek the assistance of, one's government, without fear of punishment or reprisals."  (From https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Right_to_petition)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***[Redress the balance:](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/redress-the-balance)***

> Readjust matters, restore equilibrium, as in:
>
> - *If our party wins in a few big cities, it will redress the balance of urban and rural interests in the House. **[Mid-1800s ]***

(AHD)

Balance has a long history of figurative usages, "redress the balance" is one of those,  from the mid-19th century: -

[Balance](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=balance):

> - Many figurative uses are from Middle English image of the scales in the hands of personified Justice, Fortune, Fate, etc.; thus in (the) balance "at risk, in jeopardy or danger" (c. 1300). Balance of power in the geopolitical sense "distribution of forces among nations so that one may not dominate another" is from 1701.

(Etymonline)

The following figurative usage dates back to 1843, from [The Dial](https://books.google.it/books?id=j2cvAQAAMAAJ&q=%22redress%20the%20balance%22&dq=%22redress%20the%20balance%22&hl=it&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiMuOO--4fTAhWGA8AKHebFDLkQ6AEISjAJ):

> - ..."and it now appears that we must estimate the native values of this immense region ***to redress the balance of our own judgment,*** and appreciate the advantages ..."

- There are  literal usages of the expression (see [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=redress%20the%20balance&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Credress%20the%20balance%3B%2Cc0)), but it seems that is has been  mainly used in a figurative sense.

Comment: Thank you for a great answer. Very interesting. So it seems like it just grew out of its component parts – there goes my theory! I was imagining some gold-dusted jeweller painstakingly fiddling with a tiny screw on a set of scales...ah well.